# Rendering a promise return value with React.useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I'm trying to render the value returned from a promise that calls two external APIs into the JSX.

It seems to work the first time, but then I get undefined.

Am I using useEffect the wrong way?

```
export default function Dashboard(props) {

    const [pageInfo, setPageInfo] = React.useState();

    async function getPageInfo(props) {

        try {
            const userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
            let res = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/user/'+userId);
            let lastPageId = res.data.pages[res.data.pages.length - 1];
            let pageInfoObj = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/page/'+lastPageId);
            return pageInfoObj.data;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        getPageInfo(props)
            .then(data => {
                setPageInfo(data);
            })
    }, [props]);

    return(
      <Typography>
         {pageInfo.pageTitle}
      </Typography>        
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) or initialize your data as per the response structure and put conditionals

- If response is an array, initialize with an empty array (so you can map over and get no error's) and also you can check it's length before rendering like `data.length > 0 && data.map()`
- If response is an object, initialize with null so you can check as `data && data.blah`
- If it's a string then may be an empty string

depends on response structure and it's not mandatory to have exactly same

why ? because, by the first render still the data i.e., `pageInfo` is not available yet and it will be `undefined` as it is not initialized with any value so by default is `undefined`

```
return(
      <Typography>
         {pageInfo?.pageTitle}
      </Typography>        
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a backend fetch error in the second time and also initialise your state.

In your code, when there is an error in the fetch call, it simply returns undefined; So, handle the error in the `.catch` chain.

```js
export default function Dashboard(props) {

    const [pageInfo, setPageInfo] = React.useState({});

    async function getPageInfo(props) {
        const userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
        let res = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/user/' + userId);
        let lastPageId = res.data.pages[res.data.pages.length - 1];
        let pageInfoObj = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/page/' + lastPageId);
        return pageInfoObj.data;
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        getPageInfo(props)
            .then(data => {
                setPageInfo(data);
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log("Some Error: " + err.message)
            })
    }, [props]);

    return (
        <Typography>
            {pageInfo.pageTitle}
        </Typography>
    );
}
```